# String url getting extension

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to get the extension (dk, com, org, eu) or any other domain extension from a String.

for example:

```
http://www.example.com/siteone/sitetwo/currentpage
```

From this String i would like to get the .com

I could go the very messy way around and do subString however the problem comes when an url looks like this:

```
dk.webpage.otherstuff.com/page
```

So how will i go around this in a way that doesnt require me to check everything every step of the way

Comment: Have you try using regular expressions? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: This maybe can help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234090/how-to-determine-the-file-extension-of-a-file-from-a-uri

Comment: if you have tried anything..than Show the Code

Comment: Will the strings you are checking always contain URLs?

Comment: @MrMisterMan Yes always!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the getHost() method like this:

```
public static String getDomainName(String testUrl) throws URISyntaxException {
    URI fullUri = new URI(testUrl);
    String domainName = fullUri.getHost();
    return domainName.startsWith("www.") ? domainName.substring(4) : domainName;
}
```

After you have done that then just use subString for the .com part of your domain name.

Comment: if you are directly use "www." and subString(4) won't work because now a days there are some URL which starts like www3.xyz.com  than your code will fail.

Comment: The OP can use a regex on the domainName then, depends on how detailed you want to go, with the introduction of custom domains this whole practical would be near impossible to do anyway.

Comment: @liquidsnake786 with sites like http://www.homesick.nu\ i get an error do you know why? (the error is invalid character at index 7 (meaning that \ is wrong but how come? )

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String ext = url.replaceAll(".*//[^/]*(\\.\\w+)/.*", "$1");
```

---

Some test code:

```
String url = "http://www.example.com/siteone/sitetwo/currentpage";
String ext = url.replaceAll(".*//[^/]*(\\.\\w+)/.*", "$1");
System.out.println(ext);
```

Output:

```
.com
```

Comment: @RandomGuy $1 means "captured group 1", which is the bracketed pattern to capture the dot and word chars of the extension

Answer (score 1):

Use Guava's [InternetDomainName](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/net/InternetDomainName.html#publicSuffix%28%29) class. Specifically have a look at the `publicSuffix` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

`private String getExtensionFromDomain(String domainName){
        int p = domainName.lastIndexOf(".") +1;
        return domainName.substring(p);
 }`

In case of example.co.ma  this will output :   .ma