# Getting file extension from http url using Java

Tags: java, file-extension, fileutils

Now I know about `FilenameUtils.getExtension()` from apache.

But in my case I'm processing extensions from http(s) urls, so in case I have something like

```
https://your_url/logo.svg?position=5
```

this method is gonna return `svg?position=5`

Is there the best way to handle this situation? I mean without writing this logic by myself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine the file extension of a file from a uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234090/how-to-determine-the-file-extension-of-a-file-from-a-uri).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the URL library from JAVA. It has a lot of utility in this cases. You should do something like this:

```
String url = "https://your_url/logo.svg?position=5";
URL fileIneed = new URL(url);
```

Then, you have a lot of getter methods for the "fileIneed" variable. In your case the "getPath()" will retrieve this:

```
fileIneed.getPath() ---> "/logo.svg"
```

And then use the Apache library that you are using, and you will have the "svg" String.

```
FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileIneed.getPath()) ---> "svg"
```

> JAVA URL library docs >>>
>   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html

Comment: And I have to handle MailformedException as well in this case

Comment: Yep, I forgot to mention that, but I think that is the only downside of this solution. At least in my case, I don't like the use of regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a brandname® solution, then consider using the Apache method after stripping off the query string, if it exists:

```
String url = "https://your_url/logo.svg?position=5";
url = url.replaceAll("\\?.*$", "");
String ext = FilenameUtils.getExtension(url);
System.out.println(ext);
```

If you want a one-liner which does not even require an external library, then consider this option using `String#replaceAll`:

```
String url = "https://your_url/logo.svg?position=5";
String ext = url.replaceAll(".*/[^.]+\\.([^?]+)\\??.*", "$1");
System.out.println(ext);

svg
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern used above:

```
.*/     match everything up to, and including, the LAST path separator
[^.]+   then match any number of non dots, i.e. match the filename
\.      match a dot
([^?]+) match AND capture any non ? character, which is the extension
\??.*    match an optional ? followed by the rest of the query string, if present
```

Comment: where have you find this?)
I need a reliable solution, better from a well-known and tested library.

Comment: @TyulpanTyulpan My answer should work fine, but I will add an option using the Apache library.

Comment: I was actually considering something like FilenameUtils.getExtension(new URL(url).getPath()); - but looks not so great and I need to handle exception coz of url creation

Comment: I can't comment further.  I have given you two valid solutions.